# upload git commits to external host with scp , ftp ,rsync or anything

Tags: command-line, ssh, git

I want send commits of my project to another place (etc: web host or backup server)

At the moment , I runing this command to get commit changes. and then do move files menually to destination:

```
 git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | xargs tar -cf ch.tar
```

Is there any way to change `xargs tar -cf ch.tar`  with any command (like : scp , rsync, ftp or ..) to send list of files automaticly to external server ?

Comment: can I use rsync with include arg, and get list of files from previous command?

Comment: If you can use ssh, can't you add the server as a remote to your Git repository and push to that remote?

Comment: I cant install git on my server.(it`s restricted by supervisor )

Comment: You don't need to install git on the remote. Git is perfectly happy as long as there's a bare repository on the other end and it has SSH access.

Comment: How Can I create bare repository on ssh connection? (whitout git on the server)

Comment: You may also have a look at [`git-bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) which packs commits into a single file which can then be transferred to a backup destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use xargs with scp:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD | xargs -n1 -i scp -C -P 1234 {} root@11.22.33.44:/var/public_html/{}
```